Failed building wheel for ParmEd
I am trying to install ParmEd on Windows 10 via pip install parmed and have an error:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ParmEd
  Running setup.py clean for ParmEd
Failed to build ParmEd
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ParmEd, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 17 already and updated gcc, but it doesn't help
What can I do more with it?

Are you running the above from a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt as this sets the path and environment vars up correctly.  If not you need to set the path, include and lib env vars by hand.

Why are you updating gcc when it needs MSVC?

@RichardCritten I tried, have the same
